# Count Repeated Words/Sentences

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

**UPDATE**

Sorry, i have little English.

I want to count phrase(s) in string.

My string is below;

> **Lorem ipsum** dolor **sit amet**, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla
> venenatis, **lorem ipsum** augue vel pellentesque **sit amet**, **lorem ipsum** dolor egestas lacus,
> et ipsum dolor nulla.

I want at below;

> - 3x *Lorem ipsum*
> - 2x *sit amet*

Comment: Posting the code that you've tried would allow others to either suggest a better way (rather than wasting time suggesting ways to do it that you've already tried and discarded) or improve what you have.  I would think that a Regex and counting the number of matches should work just fine, however.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time what phrases you are looking for? Or do you need the logic to pic out every multi word phrase possible? If it's the latter, is the maximum a two word phrase? What about the minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, its not quite clear what you mean by "repeated words" but i'm guessing you need to split a list of comma delimited words or phrases into single words, testing each on its own.  if thats the case:

```
string words = "I love red color. He loves red color. She love red kit. ";
myWordString = myWordString .Replace(" ", ",");
myWordString  = myWordString .Replace(".", "");

string[] words = s.Split(',');
foreach (string theWord in words)
{
    // now do something with them individually
}
```

use a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, Int32> wordList= new Dictionary<string, Int32>();
```

then once you get the word string, loop through the words in your string, and in each loop you can add to the dictionary, or increment the count

```
-- psuedo loop code from above 

if (wordList.ContainsKey(theWord)) {

    wordList[theWord] = wordList[theWord] + 1;

} else {

    wordList.Add(theWord, 1);

}

-- end psuedo loop code from above
```

and so on and so forth.  When your loop is done going through all your words in your list.. you can go through the dictionary like so:

```
foreach(var pair in wordList)
{
    var key = pair.Key;
    var value = pair.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using LINQ?

```
var wordList = words.Split(new[] { " ", ".", "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .GroupBy(x => x)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but included one word(s) like "lorem". I want to "lorem ipsum".